# Sort variables in Variable Explorer (Spyder IDE)

Tags: python, variables, spyder

I'm using Spyder IDE and I want to know if its possible to sort the variables in the Variable Explorer panel by code execution order instead of alphabetical order (I need to debug code with a lot of variables and this could be very helpful)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.